# How to allow Member to share files?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration

I have assign a test user with member permissions.

In the settings, I have enabled the following: allow members to share the site and individual files and folders

However, the user cannot share files created by other or files created by that user.

1. How to allow this user to share?
2. What permission allows user to share files/folders?
3. Can user then share everything or only the content created by him?

Answer (score 0):

Members in SharePoint Online have Edit permission level which allow user to share files.

We need to narrow down the problem and try some things.

1.Please check that the Edit permission level given to your member group is the same as the picture.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

2.If permissions are fine, try to see if other member users are also unable to share files.

Comment: Where is the share permission in your answer/screenshots?